# Making ruby gems respond to terminal commands

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, rvm

I am extremely new to ruby as well as gem making. I made a simple gem that webscrapes some information depending on the input.
However, to use my gem I need to go into the interpreter (irb) and require my gem and then call the method with some parameters.

Suppose the gem is called `foo`.
Suppose the method is called `print_website(x) # where x is a string`.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
$ foo test.com
```

and it should automatically call the method and execute it.

Thanks in advance! Please ask me for clarification if i was unclear! :D

Comment: first you need to execute require('foo'), and then you can try foo test.com. if may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it

```
$ mkdir bin
$ touch bin/foo
$ chmod a+x bin/foo
```

Edit **bin/foo**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'foo'
#Anything you want.......
```

Add following to Gemfile

```
 s.executables << 'foo'
```

Push gem. Now you published command line utility

Comment: Hi! I am still confused as to where I must actually call the method and how to provide it with ARGV[0] and ARGV[1]. Thanks!

Comment: That was awesome thanks! But one more thing, where would i add a dependancy? I require 'nokogiri' to run this and it says there was a load error and it couldnt load nokogiri. Where should I type the require nokogiri line? As of now it is in the file with the method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just run `bundle gem mygem -b` when creating your gem.