# make a ruby code as a console command

Tags: ruby, console

I created a gem with jeweler and I want a command `hat` to call a specific function in my gem. 
In Python I can put this

```
entry_points="""
      [console_scripts]
      hat = hat:hat
      """
```

in `setup.py` and it works, but how is it done in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ mkdir bin
$ touch bin/foo
$ chmod a+x bin/foo
```

Edit **bin/foo**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'foo'
#Anything you want.......
```

Add following to Gemfile

```
 s.executables << 'foo'
```

As per:

[Making ruby gems respond to terminal commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555268/making-ruby-gems-respond-to-terminal-commands)

There is also:

http://visionmedia.github.com/commander/

Answer (score 0):

For the console, you can add things to your `.irbrc` file just as you would in Python.

Within the context of the `irb` console, though, methods must be defined in the `main` namespace. Obviously you want to be careful about what you add here since it can cause confusion if you start to spike in a large number of these with arbitrary names.

Comment: I'm don't want it in irb, I want it in my terminal like in "github.com/defunkt/hub"

Comment: Oh, that kind of console. [Sunny J.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/807103/sunny-j) has the answer. What you mean is a "shell command" in this case. "console" usually refers to things like `rails console`.